# Get HTML within an <a> element using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, hyperlink, www-mechanize

I'm extracting special links within an HTML page by using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize).

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $uri );

my @links = $mech->find_all_links(url_regex => qr/cgi-bin/);

for my $link ( @links ) {
    # try to get everything between <a href="[...]">HERE</a>
}
```

The links look like this

```
<a href="[...]"><div><div><span>foo bar</span> I WANT THIS TEXT</div></div></a>
```

By using `$link->text` I get `foo bar I WANT THIS TEXT` without knowing which text was inside the `<span>` element.

Is there any way to get the raw HTML code instead of the stripped text?

In other words I need to find a way to only get `I WANT THIS TEXT` without knowing the exact text within the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Not with the things in `@links` I believe. According to the code of that module (https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.84/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Link.pm) they don't know where they are from. I think you'll have to grab the HTML of the whole page out of the mechanize and use a different parser.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.84/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#L1509 is where the TokeParser stuff gets turned into WWW::Mechanize::Link object. I don't see how you would get around that. I'd suggest using a different parser with `$mech->content`.

Comment: Please supply a sample HTML page for testing.

Answer (score 3):

As [**simbabque** has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654882/get-html-code-inside-a-href-using-wwwmechanizelink#comment76295234_44654882) you can't do that with `WWW::Mechanize`

In fact there's very little point in using `WWW::Mechanize` if you don't want any of its features. If all you're using it for is to fetch a web page, then use [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead. `WWW::Mechanize` is just a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` with lots of additional stuff that you don't want

Here's an example that uses [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) to construct a parse tree of the HTML and locate the links that you want. I've used `HTML::TreeBuilder` because it's pretty good at tolerating malformed HTML in a way similar to modern browsers

I've been unable to test it as you haven't provided proper sample data and I'm not inclined to create my own

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://www.example.com/');

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($mech->content);

for my $link ( @{ $tree->extract_links('a') } ) {

    my ($href, $elem, $attr, $tag) = @$link;

    # Exclude non-CGI links
    next unless $link =~ /cgi-bin/;

    # Find all immediate child text nodes and concatenate them
    # References are non-text children
    my $text = join ' ', grep { not ref } $elem->content_list;
    next unless $text =~ /\S/;

    # Trim and consolidate spaces
    $text =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g;
    $text =~ s/\s+/ /g;

    say $text;
}
```